# Angular - Horizontal virtual scrolling with multiple columns

Tags: angular, horizontal-scrolling, virtualscroll, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

I would like to build the attached functionality, where I have around 20k items. I have tried mat cdk virtual scroller, but it is not working as it provides a single column with a horizontal scroll.

**Note:** Boxes in the design represent checkboxes.

Please see the image below:

[image: Design]